# Cordova File plugin not working in my javascript file of iOS project, Android its working fine

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Cordova File plugin not working in my javascript file of Cordova iOS project, Android its working fine. I tried to remove the plugins and added but it's not working. Camera and Image selector is opening after that it shows FileUploadOptions not found error.

Comment: Show some code, show what's not working, etc

Comment: var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "uploadImage";
            options.fileName = imagename;
            options.mimeType = "image/jpg";
            options.headers = App.getAuthHeaders();
            options.chunkedMode = false; I am using the backbone js view for my project, inside that view in uploadphoto method after camera capture i just uploading the image into server. It shows can't fine FileUploadOptions and FileTransfer.

Comment: Write a quality question if you expect people to try to help you.